# How to do curl in php and save sessions, and eventually use a session variable

Tags: javascript, php, session, curl

I have tried to simulate mass login using javascript, by pasting a bunch of codes in the google chrome console.

These is what I basically do:

```
var data = [{u:1, p:1}, {u:2, p:2}, {u:3, p:3} ...]

function login(u,p,callback){
    $.post('/login.php', {u:u, p:p}).done(function(){
       logout(callback);
    });
}

function logout(callback){
   // delete session cookies using javascript
   callback();
}

function main(){
  // recursive function to iterate in the data collection
  login(data[counter].u, data[counter].p, function(){
     if(counter++ < data.length){
        main();
     }
  });
}
```

**Question**

How do I do that using php curl? This is specifically about how to emulate sessions so that the "only member actions" can also be access after login.

How do I clear the session, if I don't have to use destroy sessions, in javascript you would just delete the session cookies stored in the browser. In curl php, how do I do that?

**My attempt**

```
$url = 'login.php';
$fields = array(
            'u' => urlencode('1'),
            'p' => urlencode('1')
        );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

As you can see, I tried 1 set of credentials. But beyond that, I do not know what to do.

Comment: Have you tried to do anything in php?

Comment: ah, yes, should I post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`How do I clear the session?` In your php code you didn't create any session(i mean any cookie file). So you do not need to clear anything.

But however, if you need to create session/cookie, then you have to use `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`

I have modified you code a bit too. Here it is:

```
$fields = array(
    'u' => '1',
    'p' => '1'
);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));

// uncomment if you want to save cookie.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/var/tmp/cookie.txt');
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/var/tmp/cookie.txt');

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// do some other processes

// and then you can unlink('/var/tmp/cookie.txt') if you want
```